# How does making of games using game engines happen?

Tags: udk

I am a complete beginner to game programming. I have decided to give a try on UDK game engine. I have some simple doubts. I searched Google for the answers but couldn't get my doubts cleared.

This is what I have understood about a game engine:
    They are used to reduce our workload by doing the jobs which are common in games. They abstract the complex level and give us a more easier layer to work with. So when using a game engine we can concentrate on our game logic and the engine will do those complex but common tasks. 
    I understand that game engines are built over APIs like OpenGL.

Now the doubt comes:
*How do we make OUR game from a game engine?* 
Does every game engine provide a API through which we can interact with it and get our game from it?

I thought of analogy. This may not be a real analogy. Suppose we are building a house. The engine provides as a skeleton of a house in which the common works like foundations and walls which are common to all houses are given. Now we want to put a window of our choice into the house skeleton. We interact Through the API and find the position or hole where we can put our window which was made externally. Does this analogy make sense??? 
Is UnrealScript The language used to use the API provided by UDK so that our "Window" can be inserted to the "House"?

Comment: Side note: please try to be more specific in future and try and ask only 1 question at a time as this wall of text is quite confusing.

Comment: I wrote to answer the question as perfectly as possible. Basically UDK has functions that allow you to configure and display a window. You need to understand UDK well enough, you'll understand that explaining the concept of a window to the Engine is doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Extreme tl;dr

Your goal as a game developer is to provide assets and a script that describes mechanics specific to your game so the Engine can preform game logic and present game assets (rendering graphics and playing sounds an music) in the appropriate way. For this purpose there are tutorials, examples and books online. There are hundreds of useful articles on how to properly apply an Engine like Unreal to achieve common design goals. For something very specific, ask a specific question.

Think of an Engine as the things that "gets out of the way" and takes with it a bunch of responsibilities you don't want to handle; like repainting your house, cleaning the bathroom, cooking dinner, cleaning the mold in the refrigerator, fixing the broken plumbing, paying taxes, filling up your car's tank with gas before it runs out and things you take for granted like making sure the Sun lights upon this world so we don't all freeze to death and that rain pours in the winter to grow our corps. The Engine takes care of all the necessities common to most if *obviously* not truly all games.

I forgot to mention that engines often come with documentation, it is not explicitly demanded but implied that a good reliable Engine comes with tutorials and examples.

#### tl;dr summation

So basically an Engine is a huge load of hard to implement services that require sometimes myriads of women and men hours to produce.

- It loads assets from the disk.
- It handles input from the user.
- It often understands the device and offers some existing cross-platform support and native features.
- It plays music and sounds.
- It renders the game entities into the view.
- It often handles physics.
- It may handle networking, connections with the server and peers.
- It may even offer easy, streamlined ways to create content like levels.
- It often comes with existing assets, sometimes free, levels, models, animations, texture and such which could be used as place holders or fill in for some of the art at least in the alpha stage.
- Well documented and well explained, popular Engines often are often taught in books, youtube videos, blogs and other resources online.

In other words, it does **everything** that is needed for the groundwork and does not decide the rules of your game and how things look and sound but it allows you to display those things, write those rules as a human readable & programmer friendly script and play those sounds and music. It will help you to enforce some common rules like physics and collision detection.

### Longish version ("this way there be dragons"):

---

Lets clarify (generalizing) what the Engine does for you and what you do yourself.

There are certain services, that each "house" in your metaphor or Game if we get down to it, needs. These could be electricity, water, gas and higher level services like cleaning, maintenance (paint and plumbing) and cable.

What does a game need?

1. It needs to display a compelling image on the screen! A game or two with a black screen exist but this is the most common kind.

   1. The images are often changing, so it needs to display things in motion. (the walls might not be moving but the camera is hence *in motion* and not necessarily *moving*). Now if we generalize it depends if the game is 2D or 3D.

      1. 2D - We need to place sprites on the screen, this is often called "Blitting" which is basically copying 2d image data from a sprite frame to the screen. There are also more modern ways than "Blitting" that use hardware accelaration, basically placing the sprite as a texture on flat rectangular planar object and using the GPU to render it.

         1. Some 2D games require (inbe)tweening which is a way of saying how the animation is paced for a game entity.
      2. 3D - We need to talk to the 3d api (like OpenGl or Direct3D) and render models (data representation of a 3 dimensional visible entity) in real-time (this is not easy to do).

         1. If it's 3D it includes, lighting, refraction and interpolating between frames of animation too among other things.

So an engine would probably provide services that render or Blit entities to create a compelling view of the happenings in the game. You wouldn't want to write a real time rendering or "Blitting" service if you simply wish to make a game.

You would want to say, `creature.position = (x, y) // display creature at (x, y)` and it looks like this image or that model.

2. Loading assets into memory. Like we said, the creature looks like an image, an animated sprite or a 3d animated shape. It is often a piece of art, an asset that was created by an artist in a tool suited for that purpose. This data needs to come from somewhere? It often comes from a design tool, like Blender / 3d studio Max for models or Paint.net (Too many 2d tool to list) for animated sprites. It is then saved on the disk in the some file format. Someone needs to load this asset into memory for it to be handed over to the rendering service.

   1. 2D - You need to load images and understand the image format.
   2. 3D - You need to load 3D textured animated models. Often times with bone animation.

So an engine needs to understand how read files; you don't want to write a file parser. The files are on the disk in some format and you simply want to say `Load 'fileName.ext'`and the Engine needs to convert that data into something useful that could be rendered by the rendering service. The rendering service wants the data parsed (digested) and explained in the way it understands it. If the files change, you don't want to have to replace the entire rendering service, that's right?

3. Common physics - often time Engines may provide physics simulation. This is very difficult to implement on your own. Collisions are also hard to detect in 3d space or in a pixel perfect way without compromising performance and most importantly getting it bug free, unless someone who does it well, sits and invests the time to get it right.
4. Cross platform support and networking anyone? So you written your game in some low level language. Does it support other platforms and do you have stable, bug free multiplayer? Probably not. Unless you used a library like SDL/SMFL.
5. Often left unnoticed, conventions (emphasized over configuration [this is important in large teams but also for time pressed individuals]), solutions for bike shed issues.
6. Support for multiple input devices like keyboards, mice, XBOX controllers and such.
7. Some Engines come with excellent tools to create assets like levels in your game. It may even have a large database for assets for sale or ones that are free to download.

I admittedly probably missed something or glossed over some subject but this covers most of what an Engine does for you.

So what is left for you the developer?

- Write the story of your game. What is the game about not only in a narrative way; in a gameplay experience way, what journey is the player going through, what challenges does she face on her path to triumph, puzzles, monsters and traps of doom?
- Write the rules and mechanics in the game, can the player jump in the air or maybe go through solid walls? What happens when the game character kicks a Hobgoblin in the face?
- Record sound and music for your game.
- Create attractive art assets that truly suit the theme and atmosphere of your game.
- Fine tune the controls to perfection.

To apply this in practice you need to understand the scripting language used with the Engine and build a code base that describes the rules and intended functionality of your game. Like I mentioned before, there are many tutorials and examples to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

The engine is the underlying platform on which your game code sits.
The purpose of the engine is to abstract the raw driver / dx / opengl API away from us and make it easier to work with.

It merely acts as a "toolkit" on which we build our games.
Languages (such unrealscript) are simply part of that toolkit and enable us to do what we need.

Ok so for your many questions ...

> How do we make OUR game from a game engine?

We build our own logic on top of the engine API that does our "unique" game related stuff.

> Does every game engine provide a API through which we can interact
>   with it and get our game from it?

Yes, to provide an API is essentially the part of the core purpose of a game engine.

> Does this analogy make sense?

Sort of, but the engine is much higher level than that ... It says "using this function you can draw stuff and define something you call a wall, in which you can also define something you can call a window and put that inside your wall".

Engines don't worry about things in the real world like "walls" they translate your definition of a wall as shape and material information in to API calls against directX or OpenGL.

> Is UnrealScript The language used to use the API provided by UDK so
>   that our "Window" can be inserted to the "House"?

In the case of the unreal engine ... yes in a sense, "unrealscript" is a language unique to the "toolkit" that the engine provides to enable you as the developer to put games together.

Hopefully that solves your confusion?